# Библиотека .aar в JFrog Artifactory

Tags: android, maven, repository, artifactory

Здравствуйте. Проблема состоим в следующем: не могу загрузить в андроид проект библиотеку aar, с jar библиотеками проблем нет. Теги package и type не помогают!
Вот мой pom.xml

```
  <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>libs-release-local</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ecj</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mulibrary</groupId>
            <artifactId>mulibrary</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>bintray-plugins</name>
                <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>DESKTOP-I652C2G-releases</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/qwertyFox</url>
        </repository>

        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>DESKTOP-I652C2G-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/qwertyFox</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    </project>
```